# Solving a Stochastic Dynamic Programming with Vector State

Tags: stochastic-processes, dynamic-programming, linear-approximation, stochastic-approximation

Consider the following stochastic dynamic program (SDP):
$$
V_t(\textbf{s}_t)= \max_{\textbf{a}_t\in A_t(x_t)} \{(1-\lambda(a_t))V_{t+1}(\textbf{s}_t) + \lambda(a_t)(r_t(a_t)+V_{t+1}(\textbf{s}_t-\textbf{e}))\}
$$
In summary, the state of the system will change to new state $\textbf{s}_{t+1}=\textbf{s}_t-\textbf{e}$ with probability $\lambda(a_t)$ and will not change with $1-\lambda(a_t)$. The immediate reward is $r_t(a_t)$, i.e., both $\lambda_t$ and $r_t$ are functions of action taken at time $t$, $a_t$. The context for this setup is related to customer arrivals and revenue generated by that customer arriving at a period.

I can simplify the above SDP to the following form:
$$
V_t(\textbf{s}_t)=V_{t+1}(\textbf{s}_t)+\max_{\textbf{a}_t\in A_t(\textbf{x}_t)} {R_t(\textbf{s}_t, \textbf{a}_t)}
$$
where
$$
R_t(\textbf{s}_t, \textbf{a}_t)=\lambda(a_t)(r_t(a_t)-\Delta V_{t+1}(\textbf{x}_t))
$$
with $\Delta V_{t+1}(\textbf{x}_t)=V_{t+1}(\textbf{s}_t)-V_{t+1}(\textbf{s}_t-\textbf{e})$.

I can prove that for a **given $\textbf{s}_t$**, the function $R_t$ is concave in $\textbf{a}_t$. The challenge here is that state variable is a vector ($\textbf{x}_t$), not a scalar. I don't know how to approach an MDP where the state is represent by a vector.

Any kind of guidance on the next step would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where is $a_t$ entering in your problem?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? In every state, the action $a_t$ is given by a discrete set of actions the agent can take.

Comment: The input does not appear anywhere in your model. Read again what you wrote.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I have now edited the original question to include where the action comes into play.